# selecting the value from column having highest digit count after decimal places

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table named SAXTION_EG and it this table contain various colulms out of which there is one column named STR_RATE and in this columncontain values like

```
  STR_RATE
  1.11317
  123.08546759
  8.49111
```

now please advise me the oracle query by which i can select the maximum value in terms of decimal point for example in the above mentioned case the value 123.08546759 has highest decinal count so it has 8 digits count after decimal, as my objective is to fetch the value having highest digit count after decimal

Comment: What data type is str_rate, number or varchar2? If it is varchar2 (text string), can there be values like 1.00000000 - and if so, how many decimal digits is that, 0 or 8? Finally, what should be returned in the case of ties (for example, there are three values with 8 decimal digits, and 8 is the maximum) - return all three? If not, which one?

Answer (score 2):

You can try some thing like this. Logic is first get the position of the decimal point. Then get the string after the decimal. After that count the no of chars in that substring. Then use the MAX to get the aggregated max value

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(SUBSTR(STR_RATE, INSTR(STR_RATE, '.')+ 1)))
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am still not able to understand this query , please advise how it works internally

Comment: Basically I just applied the string functions to your data. Please refer this link to learn more about oracle string functions. http://www.oradev.com/oracle_string_functions.html

Comment: I get this as return type of the above query 763207461511537 so this means that there is some value in the coulumn having value after decimal place 763207461511537

Comment: yes. if you want to have a look on the value as well use this query. SELECT STR_RATE, MAX(LENGTH(SUBSTR(STR_RATE, INSTR(STR_RATE, '.')+ 1)))
FROM your_table

Comment: This isn't quite right; the number of decimal digits for an integer like 22 will be computed as 2, not 0, because INSTR will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below, I assume str_rate is of data type NUMBER, so it must be converted to character first. I added a couple of sample values to check that integer values are treated correctly, and to illustrate a case when two values have the same, highest number of decimal digits. In this case the solution returns both such values (see result set at the bottom).

```
with
     saxtion_eg ( str_rate ) as (
       select   1.11317    from dual union all
       select 123.08546759 from dual union all
       select   8.49111    from dual union all
       select 582          from dual union all
       select   0.00000001 from dual
     ),
     prep ( str_rate, char_rate, pos ) as (
       select str_rate, to_char(str_rate), instr(to_char(str_rate), '.')
       from   saxtion_eg
     ),
     final ( char_rate, dec_digits, max_dec_digits ) as (
       select char_rate,
              case pos when 0 then 0 else length(char_rate) - pos end,
              max(case pos when 0 then 0 else length(char_rate) - pos end) over ()
       from   prep
     )
select char_rate as str_rate
from   final
where  dec_digits = max_dec_digits
;

STR_RATE                              
----------------
123.08546759                            
.00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

This query return the maximum value in terms of decimal point:

```
select max(STR_RATE) keep (dense_rank last order by length(STR_RATE-trunc(STR_RATE)))
from SAXTION_EG
```